# Azure AD - Add onpremisessamaccountname as a claim in JWT token

Tags: azure-active-directory, jwt, openid, azure-ad-graph-api

The objective is to add user.onpremisessamaccountname as a claim to JWT token, in a registered application with openid permission

Steps done:

1. Created ClaimsMappingPolicy as below

```
$NewPolicy = @"
{
     "ClaimsMappingPolicy":  {
        "Version":  1,
        "IncludeBasicClaimSet":  true,
        "ClaimsSchema":  [
            {
                "Source":  "user",
                "ID":  "onpremisessamaccountname","SamlClaimType": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier",
                "JwtClaimType":  "testsamaccountname"
            }
            ]
        }
}
> New-AzureADPolicy -Definition ($NewPolicy) -DisplayName "test_samaccountname_policy" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy" -IsOrganizationDefault $false
```

[image]

2. Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy to registered application object ID
   [image]
   [image]
3. In 'TEST' Registered application Manifest, Set

```
"acceptMappedClaims": true,
```

[image]

However I'm still not able to get 'testsamaccountname' or 'onpremisessamaccountname' from JWT token.

May I ask what I'm missing.

Thanks in advance^

Answer (score 1):

I registered one Azure AD application and added **`openid`** API permission like below:

[image]

Now I ran below PowerShell script to create **claim mapping policy** like this:

```
Connect-AzureAD
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('
{
    "ClaimsMappingPolicy":
    {
        "Version":1,"IncludeBasicClaimSet":"true", 
        "ClaimsSchema": [{"Source":"user","ID":"extensionattribute1","SamlClaimType":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/testsamaccountname","JwtClaimType":"testsamaccountname"}]
    }
}') -DisplayName "test_samaccountname_policy" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"
```

**Response:**

[image]

Note the  **`ID`**  of the policy from above **response** and assign it to your service principal using below command:

```
Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id serviceprincipal_ObjectID -RefObjectId policy_ID
```

To  **confirm**  whether the policy is assigned or not, you can run below command:

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id serviceprincipal_ObjectID
```

**Response:**

[image]

To assign `samaccountname` **value**  to that claim, I ran below query in **[Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)** like this:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me
{
"onPremisesExtensionAttributes": 
    {
        "extensionAttribute1": "sri"
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Make sure to set **`"acceptMappedClaims": true`** in App's Manifest like below:

[image]

Now, I generated **tokens** using authorization code flow via Postman with below parameters:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:<appID>
client_secret:<secret>
scope:openid
code:code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded the above **ID token** in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/), I got `testsamaccountname` claim successfully like this:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

To get **code**, I ran below authorization request in browser like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id= <appID>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri= https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sridevi.

I think I pretty much did the same thing except I didn't manually assign a value in ID in ClaimSchema. Should 'user.onpremisessamaccountname' an existing claim that is able to retrieve the value without manually assign one via graph explorer ? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Jenson, if you are trying to retrieve existing claim then refer to these [link1](https://laptrinhx.com/add-samaccountname-to-azure-ad-access-token-jwt-with-claims-mapping-policy-and-avoiding-aadsts50146-2819627246/#:~:text=%23Example%20App%20to%20Add%20the%20Claims%20AzureADPreviewConnect-AzureAD%20%24template,Identifier%20and%20acceptMappedClaims%20value%20%28From%20the%20legacy%20experience%29) and [link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/6472/inlcude-onpemise-samaccount-in-azure-ad-claims) where you will get that claim in **access token**.

Comment: Note that, `openid` permission is required for generating ID tokens. If your use case is to retrieve a claim in ID token, then you have to assign value via graph explorer manually.

Comment: Yes openid permission is set in the app registration. 

One notable thing is my SamlClaimType is not using the same name as JwtClaimType in claim mapping policy. Not sure if this is the cause

Comment: If you want to retrieve claim in ID token, create claim mapping policy as I mentioned in the answer with same name and ID.

Comment: Sri - In your request  may I ask how did you acquire the authorization code and feed to the body ? I was just attempting to get token via Authorization in Postman, with grant type = Authorization Code and scope = openid, which should be the same ? Thanks

Comment: You can check the updated answer where I added authorization request to get the code.